# Queries causing MariaDB to get signal 7

Tags: mariadb, crash

I have a Redhat box running MariaDB 10.3.39-MariaDB-log. There are some queries that are running that seem to cause MariaDB to get a signal 7, MariaDB will crash mark a bunch of tables as crashed and restart. I opened up a ticket with Redhat, thinking that maybe something is wrong with our server, however we came to the same conclusion that a few queries seemed to be causing the identical issues. I thought maybe it was a space issue as that mountpoint was running low, I gave it another 10TB just be safe and still the issue persists.

So that brings me here, desperate for some sort of clue.

1. I don't know how to stop these queries and they run every 30 mins.
2. I don't know how to see from where these queries are originating so I can't figure out if it's from a common source.

I would highly appreciate if someone could kindly 'point' me in the right direction.

```
default-storage-engine = MYISAM
myisam_use_mmap=1
table_open_cache = 2048
open_files_limit = 6144
thread_concurrency=32
#key_buffer_size = 4096M
key_buffer_size = 21474836480
##myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
##query_cache_size= 32M
query_cache_size= 0k
read_buffer_size = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 256M
slow-query-log = ON
long_query_time = .2
read_rnd_buffer_size = 64K
tmp_table_size = 128M
core-file
```

```
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: 240129 22:35:45 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 7 ; 
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: Server version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-log source revision: ca001cf2048f0152689e1895e2dc15486dd0b1a
f
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: key_buffer_size=21474836480
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: read_buffer_size=33554432
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: max_used_connections=12
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: max_threads=153
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: thread_count=17
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: It is possible that mysqld could use up to
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 31001963 K  bytes of m
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, 
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs 
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: Server version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-log source revision: ca001cf2048f0152689e1895e2dc15486dd0b1a
f
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: key_buffer_size=21474836480
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: read_buffer_size=33554432
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: max_used_connections=12
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: max_threads=153
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: thread_count=17
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: It is possible that mysqld could use up to
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 31001963 K  bytes of m
emory
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: Thread pointer: 0x7fb5b8000c48
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: terribly wrong...
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: stack_bottom = 0x7fb5bca02c48 thread_stack 0x49000
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x41)[0x55b55d773eb1]
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4f5)[0x55b55d299c05]
Jan 29 22:35:45  mysqld[1021462]: /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x12cf0)[0x7fbda6861cf0]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: :0(__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms)[0x7fbda6558e73]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(+0xc00475)[0x55b55d6de475]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(+0xc030e9)[0x55b55d6e10e9]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(+0xc2309a)[0x55b55d70109a]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN7handler17ha_index_read_mapEPhPKhm16ha_rkey_function+0x148)[0x55b55d29f448]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN7handler16read_range_firstEPK12st_key_rangeS2_bb+0x66)[0x55b55d2a38c6]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN7handler21multi_range_read_nextEPPv+0xbf)[0x55b55d1c5d6f]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN23Mrr_simple_index_reader8get_nextEPPv+0x52)[0x55b55d1c5df2]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN10DsMrr_impl10dsmrr_nextEPPv+0x4a)[0x55b55d1c722a]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN18QUICK_RANGE_SELECT8get_nextEv+0x3c)[0x55b55d3987dc]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x8d581d)[0x55b55d3b381d]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP13st_join_tableb+0x18e)[0x55b55d0ed90e]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN10exec_innerEv+0xa9a)[0x55b55d10fc2a]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x37)[0x55b55d10fed7]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_jP8st_orderS9_S7_S9_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0xff)[0x55b55d11002f]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP3LEXP13select_resultm+0x165)[0x55b55d110955]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(+0x5d035c)[0x55b55d0ae35c]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x5373)[0x55b55d0baeb3]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_statebb+0x215)[0x55b55d0bd835]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcjbb+0x1304)[0x55b55d0bf8f4]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x126)[0x55b55d0c0f26]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP7CONNECT+0x252)[0x55b55d19a212]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x41)[0x55b55d19a3b1]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x81ca)[0x7fbda68571ca]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: :0(__GI___clone)[0x7fbda64c3e73]
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Trying to get some variables.
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Query (0x7fb5b800f680): SELECT st, et, sr, datatype, tracebuf FROM `WEBT$VEP$AV$$2022_04_06` WHERE st>=7.025538E8 AND st<=7.025544E8 ORDER BY st ASC
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Connection ID (thread ID): 29
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Status: NOT_KILLED
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Writing a core file...
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Working directory at /mnt/winston
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Resource Limits:
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max processes             319785               319785               processes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max open files            1048576              1048576              files
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max pending signals       319785               319785               signals
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max nice priority         0                    0   
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max realtime priority     0                    0   
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us  
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Core pattern: /tmp/corefiles/core
Jan 29 22:35:46  mysqld[1021462]: Kernel version: Linux version 4.18.0-477.27.1.el8_8.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-64-02.build.eng.rdu2.redhat.com) (gcc version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18) (GCC)) #1 SMP Thu Aug 31 10:29:22 EDT 2023
Jan 29 22:35:47  systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=7/BUS
Jan 29 22:35:47  systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jan 29 22:35:52  systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service RestartSec=5s expired, scheduling restart.
Jan 29 22:35:52  systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 608.
Jan 29 22:35:52  systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.3 database server.
Jan 29 22:35:52  systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...
Jan 29 22:35:52  mysql-check-socket[1021701]: Socket file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists.
Jan 29 22:35:52  mysql-check-socket[1021701]: No process is using /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, which means it is a garbage, so it will be removed automatically.
Jan 29 22:35:52  mysql-prepare-db-dir[1021730]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /mnt/winston already, nothing is done.
Jan 29 22:35:52  mysql-prepare-db-dir[1021730]: If this is not the case, make sure the /mnt/winston is empty before running mysql-prepare-db-dir.
Jan 29 22:35:52  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:52 0 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Jan 29 22:35:52  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:52 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.3.39-MariaDB-log source revision ca001cf2048f0152689e1895e2dc15486dd0b1af as process 1021768
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority(). 
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 1650206 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 1654796 in the ib_logfiles! 
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.39 started; log sequence number 1654796; transaction id 38
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /mnt/winston/ib_buffer_pool
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240129 22:35:55
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: Version: '10.3.39-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
Jan 29 22:35:55  systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3 database server.
Jan 29 22:35:55  mysqld[1021768]: 2024-01-29 22:35:55 8 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './WWS_HAG@0024SHE@0024AV/HAG@0024SHE@0024AV@0024@00242024_01_29' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

And then it goes on and on like this for a good long while. I get it if I get no answers, but if there's something there that is blatantly obvious, please share or point me in the right direction.

Comment: How much RAM?  20GB for `key_buffer_size` seems high.  You should really use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Comment: I have asked for the switch to InnoDB a while back and was told I'm not a DBA and that this home-grown app was designed to use MyISAM to it's fullest. This system has 80GB of RAM. I read somewhere, I believe it was a MySQL howto, that key_buffer_size should be ~1/4 of your RAM which is why I set it to such. I have used Mytop to watch for high usage and enabled the slowlog to see if anything pops out at me.
NGL, I'm kind of a fanboy of yours. Your name sticks out, I'm sure you hear it all the time so won't repeat and I read your replies to a lot of people. Thank you for replying to mine.

Comment: OK.  The key_buffer caches index blocks (1KB each); free memory caches data (by the OS).  (PS, I don't sing.)

Comment: What do `st` and `7.025538E8` represent?  What datatype is `st`?  (I fishing for a workaround.)

Comment: How did you arrive at these configuration values?  If someone assisted you, they were not your friend in any way.  In the next 4 hours, I will post suggestions for your consideration to get you closer to reality.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE WEBT$VEP$AV$$2022_04_06 for analysis.

Comment: Believe it or not, I inherited this system from another admin that left.

Comment: Many systems have been inherited.  Hang in there, we will help you make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
default-storage-engine = MYISAM
myisam_use_mmap = 1
table_open_cache = 2048
open_files_limit = 6144
# or REMOVE thread_concurrency=32
key_buffer_size = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
read_buffer_size = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
max_allowed_packet = 256M
slow_query_log = ON
long_query_time = .2
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16K
tmp_table_size = 128M
max_heap_table_size = 128M
# or REMOVE core-file
```

for a likely more stable system that survives your testing.

Please post TEXT results of htop complete page 1, when time permits.

View profile, please.

Comment: Mr. Hauck, 
I implemented these suggested changes about an hour after you posted. So, far this is probably the most stable I've ever seen this system. This system has kept me up plenty of times in the past. I inherited this system and was told 'dont worry about it because some DBA help is coming.' I finally got tired of being woken up in the middle of the night and I came here for help. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Thanks for your positive feedback.  Still would like to see the SHOW CREATE TABLE requested.  More opportunities are available. view profile please.

Comment: @AnthonyBenavidez Any chance we could talk in English by Skype TALK?  My Skype ID is  wlhauck@aol.com

Answer (score 0):

> I opened up a ticket with Redhat

You should have opened a ticket with MariaDB, as the error message suggests. The server seems to try to access an invalid memory location while reading an index on the table called `WEBT$VEP$AV$$2022_04_06`, so may be dropping and re-creating whatever indexes exist on that table will help.

Knowing "how to stop these queries" or "see from where these queries are originating" won't help you with the root cause, but if you want to know these things, perhaps ask a separate question, because the fact that your server crashes is irrelevant to that.

Comment: Ahh..thank you. That's exactly why I came here, in all the logs, I thought I kept seeing something what looked like a memory setting. I was thinking this can't be a memory issue can it? I know I'm not the sharpest tool in the toolbox I just needed some type of clarity and I'm glad I came here to ask. I will do that open a ticket with MariaDB.